Websocket disconnects during normal operation
I'm using the ESP8266 Wi-Fi SoC to send data to a server, but the connection intermittently drops during normal operation. For instance, from the PowerShell prompt, I can see the counter repeatedly running from 1 to 10 in a loop, but at some point, the connection suddenly cuts off. Though the reconnection mechanism I've implemented in the client code successfully restores the connection, but I wonder why the connection intermittently drops.
Client: ESP8266 Wi-Fi SoC (using the ArduinoWebsockets library)
Server: PC on the Wi-Fi network "NETGEAR37" (running Node.js)
my code : GitHub - wenner30/ArduinoWebsockets: ESP8266 send data to a server
Thanks for everyone's help!
code on the client side:
#include <ArduinoWebsockets.h>
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
const char* ssid = "NETGEAR37";  // Enter SSID
const char* password = "000";  // Enter Password
const char* websockets_server_host = "192.168.0.13";  // Enter server address
const uint16_t websockets_server_port = 80;  // Enter server port

using namespace websockets;

WebsocketsClient client;
unsigned long lastReconnectAttempt = 0;
const unsigned long reconnectInterval = 2000;  // 2 seconds
unsigned long lastPingTime = 0;
unsigned long lastCounterSendTime = 0;
const unsigned long counterInterval = 1000;  // 1 second between counter increments
int counter1 = 1;  // Initialize the counter
bool isCounterRunning = false;  // Control whether the counter is running

#ifdef DEBUG_ESP_PORT
#define DEBUG_MSG(...) DEBUG_ESP_PORT.printf( __VA_ARGS__ )
#else
#define DEBUG_MSG(...)
#endif

// Global variable to store received message
String receivedCommand = "";

// WiFi and WebSocket setup
void setup() {
    Serial.begin(115200);

    delay(3000);  // Optional bootup delay for stability
    DEBUG_MSG("bootup...\n");
WiFi.setSleepMode(WIFI_NONE_SLEEP);

    // Connect to WiFi
    WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
    WiFi.setSleepMode(WIFI_NONE_SLEEP);
    // Wait for WiFi connection
    for (int i = 0; i < 10 && WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED; i++) {
        Serial.print(".");
        delay(1000);
    }

    // Check if connected to WiFi
    if (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
        Serial.println("No Wifi!");
        return;
    }

    Serial.println("Connected to Wifi");
    connectToWebSocket();

    // WebSocket message callback
    client.onMessage([&](WebsocketsMessage message) {
        receivedCommand = message.data();  // Store the message to be processed later
    });
}

// WebSocket connection function
void connectToWebSocket() {
    if (client.connect(websockets_server_host, websockets_server_port, "/")) {
        Serial.println("Connected to WebSocket server!");
        client.send("Hello Server");
    } else {
        Serial.println("Failed to connect to WebSocket server");
    }
}

// Start the counter
void startCounter() {
    isCounterRunning = true;
    Serial.println("Counter started");
}

// Stop the counter
void stopCounter() {
    isCounterRunning = false;
    Serial.println("Counter stopped");
}

// Reset the counter
void resetCounter() {
    counter1 = 1;
    Serial.println("Counter reset to 1");
}

// Handle commands from the server
void handleCommand(const String& command) {
    if (command == "From server: on") {
        startCounter();
    } else if (command == "From server: off") {
        stopCounter();
    } else if (command == "From server: reset") {
        resetCounter();
    } else {
        Serial.println(command);
    }
}

void loop() {
    //DEBUG_MSG("loop %d\n", millis());

    // Send a ping message every 30 seconds to keep the connection alive
    if (millis() - lastPingTime > 30000) {
        client.ping();
        lastPingTime = millis();
    }

    // Attempt reconnection if disconnected
    if (!client.available()) {
        if (millis() - lastReconnectAttempt >= reconnectInterval) {
            lastReconnectAttempt = millis();
            connectToWebSocket();
        }
    } else {
        client.poll();  // Poll for incoming messages
    }

    // Process the received command outside the callback
    if (receivedCommand != "") {
        handleCommand(receivedCommand);  // Process the command
        receivedCommand = "";  // Clear the message once processed
    }

    // Periodically send the counter value to the server every 1 second, only if counter is running
    if (isCounterRunning && millis() - lastCounterSendTime > counterInterval) {
        if (client.available()) {
            String counterMsg = "counter: " + String(counter1);
            client.send(counterMsg);

            counter1++;  // Increment the counter
            if (counter1 > 10) {
                counter1 = 1;  // Reset the counter after reaching 10
            }

            lastCounterSendTime = millis();  // Reset the send timer
        } else {
            Serial.println("Not connected to WebSocket server, cannot send counter");
        }
    }

    // Check if there's data available in the Serial monitor
    if (Serial.available() > 0) {
        String input = Serial.readStringUntil('\n');  // Read the input from Serial Monitor
        input.trim();  // Remove any leading or trailing whitespace

        if (client.available()) {
            client.send(input);  // Send the input to the WebSocket server
            Serial.print("Sent to server: ");
            Serial.println(input);  // Print confirmation of sending
        } else {
            Serial.println("Not connected to WebSocket server");
        }
    }

    delay(100);  // Reduced delay for better responsiveness
}

code on the server side:
const readline = require('readline'); // Import readline for interactive input

// Create a WebSocket server on port 80
const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ port: 80 });

console.log("WebSocket server listening on port 80");

let clientSocket = null; // Store the connected client

wss.on('connection', function connection(ws) {
  clientSocket = ws; // Store the client connection
  console.log('Client connected');

  // When a message is received from the client
  ws.on('message', function incoming(message) {
    console.log('received data:', message.toString());
    // Send an automatic response
    ws.send('Server response: ' + message.toString());
  });

  // Handle client disconnection
  ws.on('close', () => {
    console.log('Client disconnected');
    clientSocket = null; // Clear client socket when disconnected
  });

  // Handle errors
  ws.on('error', (err) => {
    console.log('WebSocket error:', err);
  });
});

//Create an interface to read input from the terminal
const rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  //output: process.stdout
});

// Send message to the client when typing in the server console
rl.on('line', (input) => {
  if (clientSocket) {
    clientSocket.send('From server: ' + input);
    console.log('Sent to client:', input);
  } else {
    console.log('No client connected to send message');
  }
});

Output from the server side:
enter image description here
Output from the client side:
enter image description here
PowerShell prompt (server):
PS C:\workspace\websocket> npm start

> Node Server@1.0.0 start
> nodemon server

[nodemon] 3.1.6
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,cjs,json
[nodemon] starting `node server.js`
WebSocket server listening on port 80
Client connected
received data: Hello Server
on
Sent to client: on
received data: counter: 1
received data: counter: 2
received data: counter: 3
received data: counter: 4
received data: counter: 5
received data: counter: 6
received data: counter: 7
received data: counter: 8
received data: counter: 9
received data: counter: 10
received data: counter: 1
received data: counter: 2
received data: counter: 3
received data: counter: 4
received data: counter: 5
received data: counter: 6
received data: counter: 7
received data: counter: 8
received data: counter: 9
received data: counter: 10
received data: counter: 1
received data: counter: 2
received data: counter: 3
received data: counter: 4
received data: counter: 5
received data: counter: 6
received data: counter: 7
received data: counter: 8
received data: counter: 9
received data: counter: 10
received data: counter: 1
received data: counter: 2
received data: counter: 3
received data: counter: 4
received data: counter: 5
received data: counter: 6
Client disconnected
Client connected
received data: Hello Server
received data: counter: 7
received data: counter: 8
received data: counter: 9
received data: counter: 10
received data: counter: 1
received data: counter: 2
received data: counter: 3
received data: counter: 4
received data: counter: 5
received data: counter: 6
received data: counter: 7
received data: counter: 8
received data: counter: 9
received data: counter: 10
received data: counter: 1
received data: counter: 2
received data: counter: 3
received data: counter: 4
received data: counter: 5
received data: counter: 6
received data: counter: 7
received data: counter: 8
received data: counter: 9
received data: counter: 10
received data: counter: 1
received data: counter: 2
received data: counter: 3
received data: counter: 4
received data: counter: 5
received data: counter: 6
received data: counter: 7
received data: counter: 8
received data: counter: 9
received data: counter: 10
received data: counter: 1
received data: counter: 2
received data: counter: 3
off
Sent to client: off
Client disconnected
Client connected
received data: Hello Server
Client disconnected

Serial monitor (client):
12:47:17.150 -> .....Connected to Wifi

12:47:22.872 -> Connected to WebSocket server!

12:47:22.975 -> Server response: Hello Server

12:47:36.397 -> Counter started

12:47:36.500 -> Server response: counter: 1

12:47:37.504 -> Server response: counter: 2

12:47:38.508 -> Server response: counter: 3

12:47:39.511 -> Server response: counter: 4

12:47:40.515 -> Server response: counter: 5

12:47:41.551 -> Server response: counter: 6

12:47:42.522 -> Server response: counter: 7

12:47:43.526 -> Server response: counter: 8

12:47:44.529 -> Server response: counter: 9

12:47:45.550 -> Server response: counter: 10

12:47:46.537 -> Server response: counter: 1

12:47:47.572 -> Server response: counter: 2

12:47:48.544 -> Server response: counter: 3

12:47:49.576 -> Server response: counter: 4

12:47:50.585 -> Server response: counter: 5

12:47:51.556 -> Server response: counter: 6

12:47:52.592 -> Server response: counter: 7

12:47:53.602 -> Server response: counter: 8

12:47:54.567 -> Server response: counter: 9

12:47:55.571 -> Server response: counter: 10

12:47:56.574 -> Server response: counter: 1

12:47:57.578 -> Server response: counter: 2

12:47:58.582 -> Server response: counter: 3

12:47:59.585 -> Server response: counter: 4

12:48:00.589 -> Server response: counter: 5

12:48:01.593 -> Server response: counter: 6

12:48:02.596 -> Server response: counter: 7

12:48:03.632 -> Server response: counter: 8

12:48:04.604 -> Server response: counter: 9

12:48:05.655 -> Server response: counter: 10

12:48:06.611 -> Server response: counter: 1

12:48:07.660 -> Server response: counter: 2

12:48:08.662 -> Server response: counter: 3

12:48:09.648 -> Server response: counter: 4

12:48:10.646 -> Server response: counter: 5

12:48:11.664 -> Server response: counter: 6

12:48:12.068 -> Failed to connect to WebSocket server

12:48:12.573 -> Not connected to WebSocket server, cannot send counter

12:48:12.647 -> Not connected to WebSocket server, cannot send counter

12:48:12.748 -> Not connected to WebSocket server, cannot send counter

12:48:12.849 -> Not connected to WebSocket server, cannot send counter

12:48:12.949 -> Not connected to WebSocket server, cannot send counter

12:48:13.065 -> Not connected to WebSocket server, cannot send counter

12:48:13.133 -> Not connected to WebSocket server, cannot send counter

12:48:13.233 -> Not connected to WebSocket server, cannot send counter

12:48:13.366 -> Not connected to WebSocket server, cannot send counter

12:48:13.433 -> Not connected to WebSocket server, cannot send counter

12:48:13.533 -> Not connected to WebSocket server, cannot send counter

12:48:13.665 -> Not connected to WebSocket server, cannot send counter

12:48:13.766 -> Not connected to WebSocket server, cannot send counter

12:48:13.833 -> Not connected to WebSocket server, cannot send counter

12:48:13.933 -> Not connected to WebSocket server, cannot send counter

12:48:14.082 -> Connected to WebSocket server!

12:48:14.182 -> Server response: counter: 7

12:48:15.178 -> Server response: counter: 8

12:48:16.181 -> Server response: counter: 9

12:48:17.186 -> Server response: counter: 10

Debug log:
13:11:09.438 -> Connected to WebSocket server!
13:11:09.438 -> :wr 18 0
13:11:09.438 -> :wrc 18 18 0
13:11:09.438 -> :ack 18
13:11:09.438 -> :rn 31
13:11:09.547 -> :rd 2, 31, 0
13:11:09.547 -> :rdi 31, 2
13:11:09.547 -> :rd 29, 31, 2
13:11:09.547 -> :rdi 29, 29
13:11:09.547 -> :c0 29, 31
13:12:07.398 -> **:er -13 0x00000000**
13:12:07.461 -> :ur 1
13:12:07.461 -> :dsrcv 0
13:12:07.461 -> :del
13:12:07.461 -> :ref 1
13:12:07.461 -> :ur 1
13:12:07.461 -> :dsrcv 0
13:12:07.461 -> :close
13:12:07.461 -> :del
13:12:07.461 -> Failed to connect to WebSocket server
13:12:09.472 -> :ref 1
13:12:09.514 -> :wr 239 0
13:12:09.514 -> :wrc 239 239 0
13:12:09.514 -> :ack 239
13:12:09.514 -> :rn 129
13:12:09.514 -> :c0 1, 129
13:12:09.514 -> Connected to WebSocket server!
13:12:09.514 -> :wr 18 0
13:12:09.514 -> :wrc 18 18 0
13:12:09.514 -> :ack 18
13:12:09.514 -> :rn 31
13:12:09.591 -> :rd 2, 31, 0
13:12:09.591 -> :rdi 31, 2
13:12:09.591 -> :rd 29, 31, 2
13:12:09.632 -> :rdi 29, 29
13:12:09.632 -> :c0 29, 31
13:13:07.379 -> :er -13 0x00000000
13:13:07.445 -> :ur 1
13:13:07.445 -> :dsrcv 0
13:13:07.445 -> :del
13:13:07.445 -> :ref 1
13:13:07.445 -> :ur 1
13:13:07.445 -> :dsrcv 0
13:13:07.445 -> :close
13:13:07.445 -> :del
13:13:07.445 -> Failed to connect to WebSocket server
13:13:09.445 -> :ref 1
13:13:09.445 -> :wr 239 0
13:13:09.445 -> :wrc 239 239 0
13:13:09.445 -> :ack 239
13:13:09.445 -> :rn 129
13:13:09.445 -> :c0 1, 129
13:13:09.445 -> Connected to WebSocket server!

I've confirmed that the buffer isn't filling up and that the Wi-Fi signal is strong. The only clue I have is from the Arduino IDE debug feature, which shows error code :er -13 (0x00000000) when the disconnect happens.
